# Angular always sending Cache-Control: no-cache for <img> source

Tags: angular, angular-httpclient

I have noticed that in the HTTP Request headers for all the images on my site there is a no-cache header.

Following is a Request Headers:

```
Host: images.myhost.net
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:67.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/67.0
Accept: image/webp,*/*
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Connection: keep-alive
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
```

I do not want any "no-cache" flags in the requests. I have tried writing an interceptor for the HTTP calls that sets a different Cache-Control header but my interceptor was only working for calls made via the angular http client and not from HTML `<img>` tags.

I am wondering why there is a no-cache header in every request and how to disable it.

Comment: As far as I know you need to set the `Cache-Control` headers on the server as a Response Header. The server indicated to the client how it wants the caching to happen.

Comment: You have caching disabled in Chrome's developer console..... Close the console.